# Android Studio: в версии 0.4.0 странно создает проект

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Здравствуйте! Попробовал создать новый проект после обновления Android Studio 0.4.0 и получил очень странную и не запускающуюся структуру проекта:

[image]

Img [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49tqO.png).

По поводу ошибки

```
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'MyApplication2'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
```

нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614477/gradle-failure-could-not-determine-which-tasks-to-execute), но способ решения проблемы, указанный в нем, мне не помог.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

UPD: так же отсутствует папка gen c автосгенерированными классами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мне кажется, что студия не видит папку с ресурсом, точнее она не считает ее ресурсами.
и лечится это должно в gradle. я знаю, как это сделать в ручную, но это может слететь после сборки с помощью gradle.  но вот в gradle не знаю как это исправить

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в поддержке Gradle. Без gradle он нормально работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал снести студию полностью, а потом установить заново. Чтобы не было никаких update/upgrade и прочего. Возможно, все дело в некорректном обновлении.

Comment: @web_alex - ого вы некропост откопали)) Уже как релиз студии вышел))

Comment: @ua6xh, та я тоже удивился версии 0.4.0. Кстати, нашел пост в ленте справа.
LOL! На дату не посмотрел - 15 января. Прошло ровно 11 месяцев.

Про студию знаю. Снес старую, поставил новую.